# Truffle init not creating Migration.sol file

Tags: solidity, truffle, migrate, ganache

Output for `truffle version` command:

"Truffle v5.5.27 (core: 5.5.27)
Ganache v7.4.0
Solidity - 0.8.16 (solc-js)
Node v16.16.0
Web3.js v1.7.4"

`truffle init` does give a success message as below

"Init successful, sweet!

Try our scaffold commands to get started:
$ truffle create contract YourContractName # scaffold a contract
$ truffle create test YourTestName         # scaffold a test"

and creates folders and truffle-config.js(refer screenshot) but does NOT create Migration.sol file.

I did try to run the command with sudo but to no avail.
I am using a mac m1.
Please advise.

Comment: did you run `truffle migrate`

Answer (score 5):

At last I have got the solution of it. In this case, no need to use truffle init command. You just simply need to go through the command:

`truffle unbox`

or,  you can also set more specific path with the same command:

`truffle unbox metacoin [PATH/TO/DIRECTORY]`

100% working...

Comment: By the way, this is working for all OS (i.e: Windows, Linux-mint, mac)

Answer (score 2):

According this [thread](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/5532#issuecomment-1244147355), Truffle has removed the inclusion of Migration.sol on npx truffle init command since v5.5.27. Now when you run npx truffle init, it includes the following -

- an empty contracts folder.\
- an empty migrations folder.\
- an empty test folder.\
- a .gitignore file. \
- a truffle-config.js file.\